# Где хранить параметры для Ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Мое приложение состоит из множества таблиц с данными. Каждая таблица имеет сортировки и фильтры (везде разные). Обычный запрос к API выглядит примерно так:

```
axios.get('path/to/api/users', { params: {
  sort: {
    byField: 'name',
    orderBy: 'DESK'
  },
  filters: {
    status: 'active',
    country: 'spain'
  },
  search: 'pablo'
}});
```

И структура стора выглядит примерно так:

```
entities: {
  users: {
    byId: {
      0: {},
      1: {},
    },
    allIds: [0, 1]
  },
  posts: {
    byId: {
      0: {},
    },
    allIds: [0]
  }
}
```

И возник вопрос где хранить объект `params`. В отдельном редьюсере? В контейнере (`this.state`)? Или же вообще в `query string` в URl?

Если хранить объект `params` в `query params` в URl то при переходе между страницами внутри приложения я вынужден запрашивать данные с сервера еще раз.

Можно сделать отдельный редьюсер `filters` который будет привязан к ui.

```
table1: {
  idsByFilter: {
    filter1: []
    filter2: []
  }
},
table2: {
  ...
}
```

Но проблема остается в том что объект `params` нельзя (я так думаю) представить в виде ключа объекта `idsByFilter`.

Comment: данные можно запрашивать в hoc контейнера - можно в него захардкодить (если параметры не меняются пользователем)

Comment: параметры меняются пользователем

Comment: тогда не понятно из вопроса, как вы его планируете хранить, если это переменная динамическая. видимо надо генерировать на лету исходя из действий пользователя (которые отражаются в стейте). В общем непонятно. Если выложите больше кода, будет яснее

Comment: Кода еще нет (приложение на стадии проектирования архитектуры). Собственно мой вопрос как и где хранить его. Объект `params` генерируется на лету (пользователь нажимает колонку "статус" и теперь происходит сортировка по полю статус т.е. `params: { sort: { byField: 'status' } }`)

Comment: можно хранить в URI, но нужно будет кэшировать ваши запросы к апи, тогда одинаковые запросы не будут повторятся... Если вас это устраивает, то посмотрите как реализовано в apollographql

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать использовать redux-fractal или recompose withState. Скажем у вас есть страницы, которая показывает список-таблицу пользователей. В этом случае потребуются следующие составляющие:

1) Тупой компонент UserTable, который получает список пользователей и рендерит в таблицу (никакой логики)

2) Тупой компонент TableFilter - тут пользователь фильтрует результаты по стране, по статусу и тд. Никакой логики

3) контейнер UsersPage - который получается результаты запроса и рендерит UsersTable с этими результатами, а также рендерит TableFilter с текущим состояние фильтра

4) HOC redux-fractal для хранение состояния фильтра и соотв. экшенов

5) HOC withData - для осуществления запроса (это мы пишем сами или ищём в npm)

Теперь примерная схема работы...
Использован recompose withState, но в случае большого количества экшнов и если нужен персис - советую редакс-фрактал

```
// components/UserTable.js
const UserTable = ({ users }) => (
  <div>
    {users.map(user => user.name)}
  </div>
);

// components/TableFilter.js
const TableFilter = ({ active, country }) = (
  <div>
    Filter 'Active':
    <input type="checkbox" checked={isActive} onChange={onActive} />
  </div>
);

// components/PageLayout.js
const PageLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

// components/Loader.js
const Loader = () => "Loading...";

// components/Error.js
const Error = () => "Error...";




// containers/PageContainer.jsx

import { compose, withStateHandlers } from 'recompose';

export const UserPage = compose(

  withStateHandlers(
    props => ({
      filterActive: false,
    }),
    {
      setFilterActive: (state, props) => payload => ({
        ...state,
        filterActive: payload
      })
    }
  ),

  // https://github.com/esphen/fetch-hoc
  fetch(props => `http://server/users/?active=${props.filterActive}`)

)
(props => {

  const { loading, error, data } = props;

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <Error />;
  }

  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <TableFilter
        active={}
        onActive={}
      />

      <UserTable
        users={data.users}
      />

    </PageLayout>
  );


};
```

Comment: далее эту тему можно развить, если у вас много разных таблиц данных можно унифицировать всё это дело абстрагировав на уровень выше